# Zend Framework 2 tableGateway pattern workflow with other tables

Tags: database, zend-framework2

I am just getting to grips with Zend Framework 2 Database theory, having used version 1 for a long time. I am trying to discern the 'right' way of working with many tables when the business logic requires one table object to defer operations to another table object.

It seems like a lengthy and laborious process to instantiate a different table class in the existing gateway class. If I use the same process as the service manager factory, e.g.

```
$yourData = $myData['thisPart'];
$dbAdapter = $this->_myTableGateway->getAdapter();
$resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
$resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new TestObject());
$tbl = new TestTable(new TableGateway('tbl_name', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype));
$tbl->insertSomeData($yourData);
```

... then I suppose it will work, but the service manager is not supposed to be available in the table class. I could inject it using the factory definition but that doesn't seem like a great idea.

So I suppose my question is, what is the best way for a class (representing a table and using this pattern) to insert some of its data into another table using a different gateway class. Or is the method above the only/'right' way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the best approach for this problem would be to implement the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface interface in each model that needs to interact with other table gateway classes. You can then define the setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl) method which is passed a reference to the Service Locator automatically.

Comment: As I understand it this would be an anti pattern, as your objects depend on the service locater which can be altered everywhere.
The factory and injecting your dependencies there would probably be a nicer solution

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Example would be: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/Authentication/Adapter/AdapterChainServiceFactory.php there are more examples almost all which uses the factoryinterface. Pull the requirements from the service locator, and inject them so the dependencies are always set in 1 place.

Comment: I can't see what in that class you're referring to. That example has the serviceLocater passed to it and uses that to get some option data.

Comment: Yes and with those options you would instantiate your model, and fetch it with the service locator so that it will be configured in only one place and the model does not depend on the service locator itself.

Comment: That does depend on the service locator then. Not sure how that example is different from my suggestion.

Comment: Only the factory not the model itself